# sql self join on subquery

Tags: sql

So I have a query to implement as:

> Show the province that has more patients identified as 'M' than 'F'.
> Must only show full province_name

provinces table has province_id, province_name, while patients has gender, province_id and other attributes.

My approach is to first determine frequency of each gender for provinces:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT province_name, gender, count(gender) as freq from provinces
  INNER JOIN patients
  ON provinces.province_id = patients.province_id
  GROUP BY province_name, gender
)
as province_gender_freq
```

Now I plan to make a self join on province_gender_freq with join conditions as needed.

Is it optimum way of achieving it?

Comment: please add a tag which RDMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to compare to compare the count of male patients against the count of female patients:

```sql
SELECT pr.province_name
FROM provinces pr
INNER JOIN patients pa
    ON pa.province_id = pr.province_id
GROUP BY pr.province_name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) >
       COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.gender = 'F' THEN 1 END);
```

Comment: Having clause acts on results of GROUP BY. Here we don't have gender in results of GROUP BY, still it works. How?

Comment: @Mandroid Gender is not available to _select_, which step happens after the `GROUP BY` aggregation.  Gender _is_ available during aggregation, provided that we refer to it with an aggregate function like `SUM` or `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `SQL Server` or `Oracle` we can use `IIF`. In case of `MySql` use replace `IIF` with `IF`.

You can use `HAVING` and add condition as `SUM(IIF(gender='F', 1, -1)) > 0`. And update your select statement to get correct frequency for 'F' use `SUM(IIF(gender='F', 1, 0)) as freq`. Use `GROUPBY` with only `province_name`.

```
SELECT province_name, SUM(IIF(gender='F', 1, 0)) AS Freq
FROM provinces
INNER JOIN patients
ON provinces.province_id = patients.province_id
GROUP BY province_name
HAVING SUM(IIF(gender='F', 1, -1)) > 0
```

---

Alternatively we can use `CASE WHEN` instead of `IIF` which is supported by all dbms. Here is query using `CASE WHEN`.

```
SELECT province_name, SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS freq
FROM provinces
INNER JOIN patients
ON provinces.province_id = patients.province_id
GROUP BY province_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh, Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer. Feel free to edit answer if you wish to improvise in it.

Comment: I'd use a `case` expression instead, some more typing but supported by all dbms's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using Sum and also you can get how many M is more then F:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT province_name, gender, count(gender) as freq, SUM(CASE WHEN gender='M' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) SumGender
   from provinces
  INNER JOIN patients
  ON provinces.province_id = patients.province_id
  GROUP BY province_name, gender
)
as province_gender_freq
WHERE province_gender_freq.SumGender>=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE as 
(select province_id, count (case when gender = 'M' then 1  end) as n_male,
count (case when gender = 'F' then 1  end) as n_female
from patients 
group by province_id)
select province_name from province_names join
CTE on province_names.province_id = CTE.province_id
where n_male > n_female ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT province_name
FROM (
    SELECT
      province_name,
      SUM(gender = 'M') AS n_male,
      SUM(gender = 'F') AS n_female
    FROM patients pa
      JOIN province_names pr ON pa.province_id = pr.province_id
    GROUP BY province_name
  )
WHERE n_male > n_female
```